# not getting data from .env file in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables

js and i'm getting error with accessing data from .env file.

my file structure looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUint.png)

in .utils folder i have file mail.js where i need to access port and other data from .env

mail.js

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: "../.env" });
    
const port = process.env.email_port;
const host = process.env.email_host;
const user = process.env.email_user;
const pass = process.env.email_pass;

console.log("port", port); //undefined
```

getting undefined here.

Note: path is correct to .env and variable names are also correct.

Comment: Try `const { parsed, error } = require("dotenv").config(); console.log(error); console.log(parsed);` Also, from the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv): _As early as possible in your application, import and configure dotenv [...]_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `require("dotenv").config()` to the server app or to remove the `{ path: "../.env" }` from the `require`-statement.

Comment: Hi it is already in index.js file and working there perfectly.

require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env" });



const HOST = process.env.HOST || "localhost";
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
const BASE_API_URL = INTERNAL_LINKS.BASE_API_URL;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server just started at http://${HOST}:${PORT}${BASE_API_URL}`);
});

Comment: It works after removing the path from require line.

Thank you.

Comment: You wellcome =)